# Wordpress option com_jce should not work

Tags: urls

I have a Wordpress site that is getting hits from abusers trying to see if the site is Joomla.
Can you tell me why their posts to index.php\option=com_jce returns HTTP 200 response code if Wordpress doesn't have com_jce?

Comment: Because it doesn't have com_jce, so it just ignores the query string (assuming you meant a query string).

Comment: Ok. That's what I thought, but if I set a bogus value option=com_jce2 it returns 404, which I cannot understand the difference if neither exist.

Comment: It redirects to `/option=com_jce` and returns a 404 http status code on my site, unable to reproduce your issue. Also, bots don't care what your HTTP status code is, they send the request then move on to the next target, checking if it worked is expensive and wastes time, if it works it'll phone home or fire more requests to spread the infection